# How to restore Eclipse Welcome Page?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

My standard Eclipse "Welcome Page" is blank. How do I restore this page so that it shows the original links? The welcome page for the Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Tooling) will display. All of the help sections are still accessible.

Here are some details of my environment:

- Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1
- Windows 7
- A whole bunch of plugins

This is not much to go on, I know. I could post all the logs from my installation details, but those would go on for pages. My Eclipse installation on Xubuntu has all the same plugins and the welcome screen still displays the links.

- Has anyone else run into this problem recently and been able to resolve it, if so how?
- What installation details should I look at or post to help debug this problem?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try going to Help → Welcome.

Comment: Oh, okay. When you create a new workspace, does the welcome page appear?

Comment: Yes. However, when I close the welcome page and reopen it using Help -> Welcome, I get a blank page. I can get back to the welcome page by clicking on an item from the welcome toolbar that is on the status bar. When I restart eclipse, the welcome toolbar is gone.

Comment: I can't even find that help page. Where should I find it?

Comment: Ohh, I found it. 
It is on the navbar items.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the current installation, and unzip a freshly downloaded copy.

Comment: Ok, I know I can export/import my settings, but how about efficiently getting all of my plugins transferred over?

Comment: Reinstall them through the Eclipse Marketplace.  It is most likely a broken plugin that has brought you in your current situation.

Answer (score 1):

Help -> Welcome then click Customize icon at top right corner and the select Apply setting to all products sharing this workbench and click Save As.. Save the file name with Welcome2.html

Answer (score 1):

Help -> Welcome.    then use the "home" button

[image: home button]